# Getting exit code of boost::process::child under boost::asio::io_service?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

The following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::process::child c("/bin/ls");
    ios.run();
    std::cout << c.exit_code() << std::endl;
}
```

outputs `383`:

```
$ g++ test.cc
$ ./a.out
383
```

I would expect it to output `0`, as `/bin/ls` completes successfully.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to `wait` for child process to finish.  From the documentation for [boost::process::child::exit_code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idm45477675646672-bb)

> The return value is without any meaning if the child wasn't waited for
>   or if it was terminated.

So I would expect the following to give the expected result...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

int main ()
{
    boost::process::child c("/bin/ls");
    c.wait();
    std::cout << c.exit_code() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: But in the boost::process tutorial: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io It says `ios.run()` will block until child is finished.

Comment: Yes, but that example uses the io_service and an async_pipe to capture the process standard output.  The code you have, however, doesn't make any use of the io_service in the sense that `ios.run()` has no operations to wait on and will, therefore, return immediately.  Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Ok then, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157240/boostprocess-async-io-example-doesnt-work   I observe the same problem with the example from boost process tutorial.

Comment: @G.M. Indeed io_service must be passed as a parameter for `run()` to imply the command completed

Answer (score 0):

As a simple alternative, you can use [boost::process::on_exit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/process/on_exit.html) with a `std::future<int>`:

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
std::future<int> exit_code;
boost::process::child c("/bin/ls", ios, boost::process::on_exit=exit_code);
ios.run();
std::cout << exit_code.get() << std::endl;
```

The call to [`std::future<T>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) will unlock as soon as the future has a value.