# boost::process async IO example doesn't work?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

The following program:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::process;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    std::vector<char> buf(4096);

    bp::async_pipe ap(ios);

    bp::child c("/bin/ls", bp::std_out > ap);

    boost::asio::async_read(ap, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
            [](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t size){});

    ios.run();
    int result = c.exit_code();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

outputs `383`.  I would expect it to output `0`.

This is very nearly a copy-and-paste of the example from:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `c.wait()` before retrieving the exit_code?

Comment: @m88: See the example in the docs.  It doesn't have one.  Is the example wrong?

Comment: What platform/boost version is this? 1.71? It worked with Boost 1.66 for me. ISTR some changes dealing with native process wait status codes vs. exit-codes (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732569/cant-get-segmentation-fault-exit-code-from-boost-child-process/57733210#57733210). Perhaps something regressed there.

Comment: Here's a live demo on Coliru (boost version 1.66) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ffa1b882204a9cc

Comment: @sehe: Yes, I'm using 1.71

Comment: Try `bp::child c("/bin/ls", bp::std_out > ap, ios);`.

Comment: @KlemensMorgenstern: Doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a few issues here.  Firstly, I think the comment in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io)...

> Passing an instance of boost::asio::io_service to the launching
>   function automatically cause it to wait asynchronously for the exit,
>   so no call of wait is needed

...refers to the example *after* the code you've shown.  Specifically...

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
std::vector<char> buf(4096);

bp::child c(bp::search_path("g++"), "main.cpp", bp::std_out > boost::asio::buffer(buf), ios);

ios.run();
int result = c.exit_code();
```

Where the `io_service` is passed by reference to the `child` ctor.

The comment is also slightly misleading.  While it's true that the subsequent call to `ios.run()` *does* wait asynchronously for the exit it also appears (boost 1.71.0) that the exit code is not fixed up as one might hope.  The exit code is stored within the `child` class as...

```
std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<int>> _exit_status;
```

From a quick scan of the source code it seems `_exit_status->store(...)` is only invoked from the following members...

```
boost::process::child::running
boost::process::child::wait
boost::process::child::wait_until
```

So, even though the process has exited (assuming all went well) when `ios.run()` returns one or more of `running`, `wait` or `wait_until` must be called to make the exit code available.

As commented elsewhere by @sehe this looks like it's possibly a regression.  If I can find a bug report I'll update this.  In the meantime the workaround is to simply call `c.wait()` before `c.exit_code()`.

Comment: Thanks for diving into that. Looks like a clear bug indeed.

Comment: Remind me to no accept pull requests as easily. This is in deed a bug, since the whole wait handling will only occur when you pass in `on_exit`. It filters for that, if no handler for the asynchronous event is there it gets ignored.

https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process/blob/develop/include/boost/process/detail/posix/io_context_ref.hpp#L90

Comment: @KlemensMorgenstern: I opened github issue here with link to this question: https://github.com/boostorg/process/issues/112